# Do something once jQuery plugin has loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, coffeescript

I'm dynamically loading `jQuery` and `jQuery UI` into a page, and I need to know when `jQuery UI` has successfully extended `jQuery`.

At the moment I'm using the `readystate` of the script element that loads `jQuery UI` to trigger the running of my code, but I think that at that point, the script has loaded, but `jQuery UI` hasn't been properly initialised.

Is the only choice to poll until `$.ui` is defined?

Here's the code that I'm currently wrestling with:

```
(load_ui = (callback) ->
    script2 = document.createElement("script")
    script2.type = "text/javascript"
    script2.src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.7/jquery-ui.js"
    script2.onload = script2.onreadystatechange = ->
      console.log 'readystate:', @readystate
      if @readystate == "loaded" or @readystate == "complete"
        console.log "jquery ui is loaded"
        callback ($ = window.jQuery).noConflict(1), done = 1
        $(script,script2).remove()
    document.documentElement.childNodes[0].appendChild script2
    console.log 'jquery ui script element appended to page'
(window, document, req_version, callback, $, script, done, readystate) ->
  if not ($ = window.jQuery) or req_version > $.fn.jquery or callback($)
    console.log "begin loading jquery"
    script = document.createElement("script")
    script.type = "text/javascript"
    script.src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/" + req_version + "/jquery.min.js"
    script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = ->
      if not done and (not (readystate = @readyState) or readystate == "loaded" or readystate == "complete")
        console.log "jquery is loaded, now loading jquery ui"
        load_ui(callback)        

    document.documentElement.childNodes[0].appendChild script
    console.log 'jquery script element appended to page'
) window, document, "1.6.1", ($, L) ->
    console.log $
    console.log $.ui.version
```

For some reason the readystate of the jquery ui script element just returns undefined.

Comment: I'd say the ugliness is down to the code..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this will do exactly what you need, add more dependency as much as you like.

```
(function () {
        function getScript(url, success) {
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.src = url;

            var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
            var completed = false;
            script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (!completed && (!this.readyState || this.readyState == 'loaded' || this.readyState == 'complete')) {
                    completed = true;
                    success();
                    script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = null;
                    head.removeChild(script);
                }
            };
            head.appendChild(script);
        }

        getScript("Scripts/jquery-1.6.1.js", function () {
            getScript("Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.js", function () {
                alert($.ui);
            });
        });
})();
```

> ***Tested with** IE7, IE8, IE9, Firefox, Safari, Chrome and Opera*

Comment: Nice solution! Just one question : why do you remove the `script` from the `head` when it's loaded? What does it change?

Comment: It works very nice on most pages but it doesn't work on Wikipedia pages. Can you make it work on Wikipedia? Thanks.

Comment: for success() I got always this message in Chrome:Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function  . Why did I get this message?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="jquery ui"></script>
<!-- jQuery UI has been initialized -->
<script src="my source"></script>
```

Comment: I'm not loading my script from an external source, only jquery and jquery ui are being loaded externally.

Comment: The OP mentioned they are dynamically loading jQuery and jQuery UI.  I'm taking that to mean that they aren't included as `<script>` but rather are loaded by other javascript.

Comment: I'm loading them by inserting script tags into the document, and running my code when they are loaded. (at least that's what I'm attempting to do)

Answer (score 0):

I used this code on some project to ensure that some scripts run sequentially. It did not work on IE (and I didn't have time to debug), but worked fine on everything else.

```
var node = document.createElement("script");
$.extend(node, {
    type: 'text/javascript',
    charset: 'utf-8',
    async: false,
    defer: true,
    src: /*...*/
});
$(node).bind('load', loadedCallback);
$('head')[0].appendChild(node);
```

Comment: How do you load a resource without inserting it into the DOM?

Comment: @Acorn: you can't, I remembered wrong about that part. See updated answer (an async loader for something I did not finish; probably needs some tweaking for IE compatibility).