# Loading jQuery and jQuery UI in Bookmarklet if they're not already loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm working on a bookmarklet which needs access to jquery-ui as well as jquery min. The concern of course being that the page may already have jQuery loaded and conflicts should be avoided.

Using Ben Alman's code at found at http://benalman.com/code/javascript/jquery/jquery.ba-run-code-bookmarklet.js I've been able to gracefully introduce jQuery and hacked in UI to load as well **but there seems to be an issue with the delay** and jQuery UI is not ready to go right away...

Is there a better way to handle loading both scripts in sequence before executing the actual code?

```
(function( window, document, jQuery, req_version, callback, callback_orig, parent, script ){

  if ( !window[jQuery] || req_version > window[jQuery].fn.jquery ) {
    parent = document.documentElement.childNodes[0];
    script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js';
    parent.appendChild(script);

    callback_orig = callback;
    callback = function($, L) {
      '$:nomunge, L:nomunge';
      $(script).remove();
      callback_orig( $, L );
    };
  }

  if (typeof jQuery.ui == 'undefined'){
   parent = document.documentElement.childNodes[0];
   scriptui = document.createElement('script');
   scriptui.type = 'text/javascript';
   scriptui.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.7/jquery-ui.js';
   parent.appendChild(scriptui);
   alert('Loading your matches...');
  } 

  (function loopy($){
    '$:nomunge'; // Used by YUI compressor.

    ( $ = window[jQuery] ) && req_version <= $.fn.jquery
      ? callback( parent ? $.noConflict(1) : $, !!parent ) : setTimeout( loopy, 50 );
  })();

})( window, document, 'jQuery', '1.3.2',

 function($,L) {
    '$:nomunge, L:nomunge';   

<all the jquery stuff goes here>
```

There's a similar question at [Using jQuery UI in a Bookmarklet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535641/using-jquery-ui-in-a-bookmarklet) with in-depth answers but I have been unable to translate this from CoffeeMarklet to "standard" js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See my gist here - This is a bookmarklet template for loading jQuery, but you can specify additional scripts and css to load before execution.

https://gist.github.com/2897748

You initialise it like this.

Edit: If you need to load dependencies, you can create an array and push things into it depending on different conditions.

```
var jsDependencies = [];

// This will only load jQuery UI if it does not exist already.
// Of course if you rely on the page's copy, you have to do some 
// more advanced things to check for versions and whatnot.
if(!window.jQuery || !window.jQuery.ui){
  jsDependencies.push('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js');
}

var MyBookmarklet = MyBookmarklet || new Bookmarklet({
  // debug: true, // use debug to bust the cache on your resources
  css: ['/my/style.css'],
  js: jsDependencies,
  // jqpath: '/my/jquery.js', // defaults to google cdn-hosted jquery
  ready: function(base) { // use base to expose a public method
    base.init = function(){
      // doStuff();
    }    
    base.init();
  }
});
```

Comment: Ahhh, spoke too soon. The page I was viewing already had UI loaded up and adding in  js: ['http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js'], is producing the error: arr is not defined, line 74 (63 of the git pub)

Comment: Oops. My apologies. ```arr``` should be changed to ```scripts```. I have updated the gist.

Comment: Also, make sure you either use 'https://', 'http://', or '//'. The last of which being a protocol-relative url. The script requires a fully qualified URI to load stuff.

Comment: hmm, you could try replacing $ with jQuery. it's possible they have jQuery loaded in noConflict mode. I'll try one of my own bookmarklets thats based on this and let you know what i find out.

Comment: Follow up on this... By replacing $() with jQuery() we were able to get jQuery's base to load on Amazon and a variety of other sites which had issues. However a conflict remains in loading UI of some sort and all UI functions fail. Don't suppose you have any ideas on how to get around that?